# Simulate UIScrollView Deceleration

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an `UIPanGestureRecognize` which I use to change the frame of a view. Is there a way to simulate the deceleration of the `UIScrollView` or `UITableView` when the gesture's state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`? Here is my current code:

```
if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(182, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                        //Do something
                     }
                 }];
}
```

but this is not a smooth scroll. I would like something that decelerates until it stops to the point I've set. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Session 223 at WWDC 2012, "Enhancing User Experience With Scroll Views", covered a method to use a scrollview's behavior and "feel" to animate the position of a different view (without the scrollview ever actually being visible to the user).

The benefit of the method shown in the session is that your deceleration would always match UIScrollView's, now and forever.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=223

Comment: I am glad this one worked for you guys back in 2013, but it would've been a better answer if you would add some actual code here, because now the video is unavailable, and even if it was available, I wouldn't be very comfortable watching it while at work.

Comment: as for me session seems to be available now. it basically says you should place somewhere an invisible scroll view, place a simple UIView in the area that should be scrollable and take that scroll's pan gestures and reattach them to the simple view. then having a scroll delegate you may take it's offset, that will be decelerating as for normal scroll view. i've got no idea what did i just watch, this is so ridiculous imo

Answer (score 1):

You would have to come up with an algorithm of some sort to calculate where you want the view to stop at depending on the velocity of the gesture, which can be obtained like this:

```
CGPoint velocity = [panGesture velocityInView:panGesture.view];
```

From there it should just be a matter of animating your view into its calculated resting place and adding an animation to get it there. I believe `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` would be appropriate here.

Comment: I know exactly the point where I want it to stop. There is no need to calculate it. However you gave me a good idea to change the animation options. UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut worked for me.

Comment: The second answer added by @Jeff is a better approach.