# Placing multiple UICollectionView cells within a single scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

**The Problem**

I am working on the problem of creating a magazine reader view. The magazine can be read 1 page at a time, or with a 2-page spread visible, depending on the view's aspect ratio.

The pages need to be zoom and pan-able (like when viewing a single photo in the photos app), and *importantly*, when in 2-page mode, the 2 pages need to zoom/pan as if they were attached in the middle as a single view.

**Current (unsatisfactory) solution**

My first (and in production) thought for implementing this is as a UICollectionView, as this provides the flexibility of reusable cells and multiple UICollectionViewLayouts (eg. a grid page-overview).

I treat each 2-page-spread as a cell that contains a UIScrollView that in turn contains 2 single-page views. I then do a lot of mapping from spread indexPaths to single-page indexes, depending on a `singlePageMode` flag.

This whole mapping of spread<->page ends up being quite inflexible. For example, I hope to add a grid-view layout, that could be easily transitioned to/from, and I would also like a nice 'page-appear' animation on the current page when switching between single/2-page mode. However, when switching the `singlePageMode` flag I have to effectively reloadData on the collectionView, and possibly manage a lot of cell movement/deletion/insertion in order to keep the currently visible page within the view.

**Ideas**

One possibility that comes to mind is making the collectionView treat individual pages as cells, and skip the whole `page spread` concept. This is a lot more satisfying to me, as the position of each page can be totally controlled by a custom layout object. However, my hangup with this solution is the panning/zooming of a 2 page spread.

I suppose I could simulate the scrollview behaviour with gesture recognizers within the layout object, but I dont think this would yield the nice momentum scrolling you get a scroll view, and would be a major, and I think possibly fragile, hack.

So, the real crux of my question is: how to zoom/pan the contents of 2 cells simultaneously, as if they were in the same scrollView.

Or, if anyone has a solution to the broader problem, I'd love to hear it.

---

If interested, the current implementation is available here: https://github.com/shopgun/verso

It evolved poorly into it's current shape, and (as you can probably see) needs a major refactor and separation of concerns, hence the above question.

Comment: What about using 2 UICollectionViews, one for each view mode. You would have to schyncronize the scroll between the two of them, but you can animate how each of these CollectionViews are shown.

Comment: You still end up with the issue of mis-matched spread/page counts, and a solution that just doesnt seem 'clean'. Possible solution I've been working on today is overlaying a transparent dummy scrollview to calculate offset/scale, and then passing those values to the layout to update layoutAttributes of the active pages (similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406681/simulate-uiscrollview-deceleration). Promising, but not finalized yet.